# Проблема в определении грамматической основы

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

*Но до самой ста­ро­сти они оста­ют­ся для нас всё теми же ма­ма­ми.*

Я полагаю, что ответ "они остаются", но в ответах мне выдает "они остаются мамами".

Answer (score 1):

*Но до самой старости **они остаются** для нас всё теми же **мамами**.*

Грамматическая основа: ***они остаются мамами.***

В этом предложении составное именное сказуемое ***остаются  мамами***.

*Остаются* — глагольная связка, *мамами* — именная часть.

Связка ***оставаться*** по смыслу близка к связке ***быть***: *они будут для нас мамами.*

Answer (score 0):

*Они станут мамами. Они стали мамами. Они остаются мамами.* Может быть, этот ряд поможет вам правильно определить сказуемое? Вернее, поможет согласиться с предлагаемым ответом?